# Language C : BOOL FUNCTION with error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘isThereSpace’

Tags: function, compilation, boolean

```
bool isThereSpace (EvernotaStruct *nota){
bool y = false;
for(x = 0; x < NUMBER_STRUCTS; x++){
    if(shmptr[x].time == 0){
        strcpy(shmptr[x].nome_nota, nota.nome_nota);
        strcpy(shmptr[x].text, nota.text);
        strcpy(shmptr[x].autor, nota.autor);
        shmptr[x].time = nota.time;
        printf(">>Nota inserida com sucesso\n");            
        y = true;       
    }
}
return y;       

}
```

I keep getting that error on console, I am doing everything right I guess :s
Thanks!

Comment: Solved , there is no bool function in C right?
only 0 and 1, 0 for false and 1 for true.
thanks anyway :)

Comment: C99 **does** have `bool` if you include `stdbool.h`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is strict C, there is no 'bool' keyword.